# Get data from Firestore with $http

Tags: angularjs, http, google-cloud-firestore

My read call to `firestore` database using the `$http` is not working.

*Code Snippet*

```
const docAdd =  "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/mydDatabaseb5b13/database/firestore/data/myCollection/myDocument";

$http.get(docAdd).then(function(response) {
    alert(response.statusText)
});
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? Any more info would be helpful to answer better. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more points

Comment: Here’s the error I get: Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://console.firebase.google.com/project/mydDatabaseb5b13/database/firestore/data/myCollection/myDocument","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}